# Tomcat6, how to interpret stop service event?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, lifecycle

I would like to take some action when tomcat service is going down. For example, I would like to simply log the stop time of the tomcat service. Is there any way to do this by applying hooks to tomcat lifecycle event ? If yes, then please provide some details. 

I would like to call one class when tomcat is going down and this class will log the time in some property file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement interface **org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener** and then register it in your tomcat configuration.. You may find how in [this document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html) in section **Lifecycle Listeners**.

Hope this helps you..

**edit:** changed URL to correct document ;-)